# how to get selected td row value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to select selected row value on button on click for this in select option i have `name="product_id"` and `class="productid"` i want value of product_id so i have this code

```
                <td>
                <select class="productid" name="product_id" >
                @foreach($findadminproducts as $a)
                <option value="{{ $a->id }}" >{{ $a->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
                </select>
                    <button onclick='linkproduct(this);'>Use Location</button>
                </td>
```

method i tried in js

```
<script>
   function linkproduct(button){
     var b = $(this).closest("td").find('select.productid').text();
     console.log(b);
}
</script>
```

but it gives empty value or if i use .val() then it gives undefined

Comment: Use `.val()`  instead of `.text()`

Comment: gives undefined in console

Comment: Than don't use inline `onclick`. Remove that attribute and use a class like `<button class="linkProduct"` and in jQuery (...have you included the jQuery library at all?) use `$(".linkProduct").on("click", linkproduct);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var b = $(button).closest("td").find('select.productid').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try with something like this :

```js
function linkproduct(button){
     var b = $(button).closest("td").find('select option:selected' ).text();
     console.log(b);
}
```